# How to create custom vector icons to use in Xcode application

Tags: xcode, macos, vector

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can make those glyph/vector icons appear like the default ones that you get with Xcode (e.g. NSActionTemplate). I researched and saw that they were saved in Illustrator to PDFs.

When I did the same trick (I managed to find the original Illustrator files for the icons by Apple) and saved it as an PDF, imported it into my project and dragged the icon onto a textured button it appeared plain black. It did however clear the white background so I thought it might be the white background that was visible in the preview that caused it to not style the button like the originals.

[image: See how it doesn't change the style of by icon, but does fine on the default.]

So basically what I'm asking is how I manage to make a icon appear like the default. I don't really wan't to make multiple files and/or code the behavior, since it should be quite easy to just drag and drop the image onto a button and apply the style itself.

**-- EDIT --**

OK, so I found the solution — By appending the text "Template" to the filename it will do this. But I still can't figure out why my transparent PDF - exported from Illustrator as AI and EPS - it still have a white background, which Xcode uses - so it will be a rectangular with the effect I want, instead of the circle.

Anyone that have an idea on how to remove the white background from the PDF so it will work in Xcode. It bugs me that it shows it is transparent (when seeing transparent grid in the PDF and Illustrator) and it still have a white background.

Answer (score 0):

The white background in the PDF (and you should always use PDF over EPS—they "play nice" with OS X) has to do with the PDF format originally being oriented toward printed content. The white background you see in Preview and Xcode is the "page" area. Fortunately, this usually goes away / gets ignored when you load the PDF into an `NSImage`, as happens when you put it on a button.

If I'm understanding correctly, the problem you're having is you place a PDF with no background on a button, and in Xcode's Interface Builder it displays as if there were a background? I was able to reproduce this behavior, and I'm not sure what caused it. But I built and ran a test app with the very same Template file and errantly-displayed NIB. And in the actual, running Cocoa app, the graphic displayed correctly.

Sometimes Interface Builder just previews wrongly. I suspect the problem is merely cosmetic in preparing the interface.

Comment: Actually I did run the app and it didn't show the icon on a default NSButton but if I used textured NSButton, it would show this square that behaves like I wan't, but isn't the shape I made - Even if I ran the application. I still haven't solved this issue yet.